# ModalPopUpExtender inside UpdatePanel causing PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, updatepanel, modalpopupextender

The following code displays a popup correctly, but when clicking on any button in the popup, an error is thrown (se below the code).

I cannot turn of EventValidation as it is needed for other purposes on the page. 
How can this be solved?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MainUpdatePanel" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional"
ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink><asp:MultiView ID="MultiViewSearchState"
        runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="ViewCommands" runat="server">
            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="btn_Click" />&nbsp;<asp:Button
                ID="ButtonClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="ButtonClear_Click" />
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="ViewSearch" runat="server">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMain" CssClass="modalPopup" EnableViewState="false">
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="ButtonCancel_Click" />
                <dyncontrols:SearchControl runat="server" ID="searchControl" ExecuteSearch="false" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <input type="hidden" id="popupDummyTarget" runat="server" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="popUpControl" runat="server" TargetControlID="popupDummyTarget"
                PopupControlID="pnlMain" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</ContentTemplate>
```

The error as shown in the Internet Explorer debugger:

```
SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

Comment: Are you calling `popUpControl.Show()` after you bind your control on postback? I also think(as Town does) that it is not necessary to put the extender into the UpdatePanel. You only have to ensure that your `pnlMain` is outside of the UpdatePanel too. Put only the content (without the popup-control itself) into the UpdatePanel.

Comment: The problem is that I only want the content inside the ViewSearch to popup, if I put the pnlMain outside the UpdatePanel ViewCommands will be affected aswell. I call popUpControl.Show() in Page_Load, not sure when I bind the control, don't think I've done that manually.

Comment: you shouldn't put `pnlMain` outside of the UpdatePanel. What i meant was, you should put the control with the ID of the ModalPopupExtender's `PopupControlID` and the extender itself outside of the UpdatePanel. You could create another div for the popup including the title bar when needed(like a normal window) and use it's ID as PopupControlID. The pnlMain etc. could stay in the UpdatePanel.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't think your `ModalPopupExtender` needs to be inside your `UpdatePanel`.

Try moving it outside and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Tried that, and got this error: SCRIPT5022: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends.

Comment: Is this a nested UpdatePanel?

Comment: I think so, yes. The searchControl inside the pnlMain has an UpdatePanel aswell.